# Are there some simple steps that one can apply with the standard flightgear Cessna aircraft to get it off the ground?

Tags: keyboard, graphics, mouse, games

I installed the standard **Flight Gear (flightgear)** flight simulator on Ubuntu.  I want to use it to test graphics cards.

However, I am struggling with it after it launches, even with the latest version.

I am able to see the scenery at the airport nicely.  But **I cannot get the airplane to launch to fly!**

I tried referencing the online help.  I am able to toggle interesting things, like getting the propeller to turn on.  Setting the brakes with **B** seems to do nothing.  Also, **m** seems to do nothing, as recommended in the **Flight Gear on-line help**.

I would appreciate some simple steps (with a mouse, and keyboard - no joystick) to get this standard Cessna aircraft off the ground.  Please also let me know what airport to select.

Some additional links that I have found are as follows:

[Cessna 172P](https://wiki.flightgear.org/Cessna_172P)

[A Basic Flight Simulator Tutorial](https://www.flightgear.org/legacy/Docs/getstart/getstartch7.html)

[FlightGear.org Chapter 6 Tutorials](https://www.flightgear.org/legacy/Docs/getstart/getstartch6.html)

Thank you to the community in advance for any help!

Comment: why not ask [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flight-simulator)

Comment: Did you have a look at the [official manual](https://flightgear.sourceforge.net/manual/2020.3/en/getstart-en.html) and [wiki](https://wiki.flightgear.org/Main_Page)? I would assume this kind of information was to be found there.

Comment: And I also think you'll have better luck on the Aviation SE, or on the Flightgear Forum.

Comment: @Artur Meinild %graham:  I tried to look at the Aviation SE briefly, but I did not see on the main page  anything Flight Gear related.  The official manual was a bit confusing for me.   I do appreciate the links.  I started reading the official manual.  But it was very confusing for me.  Because of this reason, I sought help here on the Ubuntu page where other games are also supported with the **games** tag.  Per: graham  - I can only reference one user to update an email with.  I am sorry that I could not also include you with my comments.

Comment: Stephen no problem - you are more than welcome to ask here. It was just my assumption that there would be a bigger audience for your question on the other sites. In any case, hope you figure it out eventually.

Comment: You can't just use the road? :D do you know the keys to press? Maybe check if those are not set to something different?

Comment: @graham  and Artur Meinild  : I tried a google search for "stackexchange aviation flightgear" and came up with nothing relevant on the first page.  This is probably a meta question, but is there a search option within Stack Exchange to search across ** all ** of the sites using subject title that is more effective than a Google search with the listed keywords?

Comment: Just double checking here: You read through the **startup checklist** on the Cessna wiki page, you also tried "autostart", and you read the FAQ section about "Why will the engine not start"? And after trying *all of that*, the you still can't get it to work?

Answer (score 1):

*TL;DR: Choose an airport close to sea level, and use the "Autostart" option. Starting an aircraft is a little more complicated than starting an automobile.*

This is a long shot - copy and pasted from [Cessna 172P Flightgear Wiki](https://wiki.flightgear.org/Cessna_172P):

> ##### Engine Start (manual and complex startup)
>
> - Priming: prime the engine at least 3 times
> - Mixture: Rich (red lever all the way in)
> - Throttle: Open 1/8 (black lever at 20%)
> - Parking Brake: Applied (<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>)
> - Prop Area: Clear
> - Master switch: ON (both)
> - Magnetos: Both (Press <kbd>}</kbd> three times)
> - Ignition: Start (<kbd>S</kbd>)
>
> ##### Engine Start (automatically with Autostart)
>
> - Click on the menu "Cessna C172P" and select "Autostart" in order to start the plane. Please note that the Autostart attempts to start
>   the engine with the mixture full rich, so if you are taking off from a
>   very high altitude airport you may need to manually start the plane.

From the FAQ:

> **Q:** Why will the engine not start?
>
> **A:** You can start the engine automatically by clicking on the menu "Cessna C172P" and selecting "Autostart". For a manual start, please
> follow the checklists available by clicking on the menu "Help"
> followed by "Aircraft Checklists". As seen above, the engine must by
> "primed" before starting. If oil management is activated, you must
> have enough oil for the engine to work (more than 5.0 quarts). If fuel
> contamination is activated, the fuel must be light blue in order for
> the engine to properly work. You must also make sure that the battery
> is charged enough (you can check and recharge it in the Aircraft
> Options dialog).
> Or it might be as simple as not having the magneto[s] turned on (which
> provide electricity to the spark plugs), or the fuel mix is too lean
> (put it at 100% to start) or the throttle too low (put it about
> 10-20%).
> Or even more simply make sure that the game is not paused by pressing
> <kbd>p</kbd>.
>
> **Q:** Why does the Autostart fail to start the engine?
>
> **A:** That's probably because you are attempting to take off from a very high altitude airport. Autostart always tries to start the engine
> with the mixture full rich, and if it fails to do that properly then
> you must manually start the engine after properly leaning the mixture.

Comment: Sorry to be confused, but:  From your instructions **Priming: prime the engine at least 3 times**, how can priming be done specifically?  Is there a priming button on the dash-board or what exactly?  I did get **auto-start to start the engine**.  But the plane veers off the runway, and I cannot steer it back on course.   For now, I am referencing:  **https://www.flightgear.org/legacy/Docs/getstart/getstartch7.html** in the section **7.3 The First Challenge - Flying Straight**.

Comment: I think priming is done by activating the fuel pumps. I found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tGkQ2VGLJHE). Not sure how it works in FlightGear though..

Comment: How to fly a plane is incredibly off topic here.

Comment: @OrganicMarble but it seems I have nothing better to do while the mod strike is going on .. 